# Code not creating a text file C#

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to create a program that checks if the following file exists and if not, create one and write name to it. But the program doesn't create a file and doesn't throw any exceptions.

```
        string verify;
        string name = textBox1.Text;
        string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\assets\"+ name + ".txt");
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path);
            File.WriteAllText(path, name);
        }
        else if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            verify = File.ReadAllText(path);
            if (verify == name)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you add to your question, the value of your path variable.

Comment: What did you see when you put a breakpoint on `string verify;` and stepped through your code in the debugger with the F10 key, examining each variable in the watch window (or by hovering the mouse over it) as you went? You can even select `File.Exists(path)` and hover the mouse over that to see what it returns.

Comment: [Directions for how to use the debugger in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243867.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure that the folder C:\assets exists, otherwise your program will throw an exception.
2. File.Create(path) will create the file, but when you call File.WriteAllText(path, name) it would throw an exception because your file may still be opened. Therefore you should remove File.Create(path), File.WriteAllText(path, name); will create a file and then close it after writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would eliminate `File.Create(path);` from your code and see what happens.  `File.WriteAllText(path, name);` will Create the file for you so it is unnecessary, and you may be getting an IO exception that is being swallowed up elsewhere in your code that is throwing you off the scent.